# product Unknown predicted category phpML

Tags: php, classification, prediction, php-ml

Hi  am triying to predict product category but it showing `Unknown predicted category`, please gude. I am using phpML, I have checked it is trained but not predicting.

It predicting wrong data

```
Input Data: Array ( [0] => Poor People ) Predicted Categories: array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "The Iliad" } Unknown predicted category: The Iliad
```

my books.csv is in this format

| category | title |
| --- | --- |
| Books | Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince (Harry Potter #6) |
| Books | In a Sunburned Country |

trained_model.php

```
<?php

require_once 'autoload.php'; // Correct the autoload path

use Phpml\Classification\NaiveBayes;
use Phpml\CrossValidation\RandomSplit;
use Phpml\Dataset\CsvDataset;

// Function to load and unserialize the trained model
function loadModel($filePath) {
    $serializedModel = file_get_contents($filePath);
    return unserialize($serializedModel);
}

// Verify if the model is loaded correctly
function verifyModel($model) {
    if (!$model instanceof NaiveBayes) {
        die("Error: Failed to load the model.");
    }
}

// Load the dataset from CSV file
$dataset = new CsvDataset('books.csv', 1, true); // Specify 1 as the number of columns to skip as headers

// Split the dataset into training and testing sets (80% training, 20% testing)
$split = new RandomSplit($dataset, 0.8);

// Separate features and labels for training
$trainSamples = $split->getTrainSamples();
$trainLabels = $split->getTrainLabels();

// Create and train the NaiveBayes classifier
$classifier = new NaiveBayes();
$classifier->train($trainSamples, $trainLabels);

// Serialize and save the trained model to a file
file_put_contents('trained_model.txt', serialize($classifier));

echo "Model trained and saved successfully.";

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php

require_once 'libs/phpML/vendor/autoload.php'; // Correct the autoload path

use Phpml\Classification\NaiveBayes;
use Phpml\CrossValidation\RandomSplit;
use Phpml\Dataset\CsvDataset;

// Function to load and unserialize the trained model
function loadModel($filePath) {
    $serializedModel = file_get_contents($filePath);
    return unserialize($serializedModel);
}

// Verify if the model is loaded correctly
function verifyModel($model) {
    if (!$model instanceof NaiveBayes) {
        die("Error: Failed to load the model.");
    }
}

// Load the trained model
$trainedModel = loadModel('libs/phpML/vendor/trained_model.txt');
verifyModel($trainedModel);

// Example input data
$newBook = ['Poor People']; // Assuming 'title' is the only feature used for prediction

// Check if the input features are empty
if (empty($newBook)) {
    die("Error: Title feature is empty.");
}

// Debugging: Print input data
echo "Input Data: " . print_r($newBook, true) . PHP_EOL;

// Make the prediction
$predictedCategories = $trainedModel->predict([$newBook]);

// Define category names based on your dataset
$categoryNames = ['Books']; // Replace with your actual category names

// Debugging: Print predicted categories
echo "Predicted Categories: ";
var_dump($predictedCategories);
echo PHP_EOL;

// Output the prediction result
if (!empty($predictedCategories) && is_array($predictedCategories)) {
    $predictedCategory = $predictedCategories[0]; // Assuming only one prediction is made
    if ($predictedCategory !== "") {  // Check for empty string
        if (isset($categoryNames[$predictedCategory])) {
            $predictedCategoryName = $categoryNames[$predictedCategory];
            echo "Predicted Category: $predictedCategoryName" . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            echo "Unknown predicted category: $predictedCategory" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    } else {
        echo "Empty predicted category" . PHP_EOL;
    }
} else {
    echo "No prediction" . PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

Comment: Why don't you show the value of `$predictedCategories`? It's basic debugging...

Comment: @Olivier It is prediction is not matching where as in my data sheet title existed, please help to fix it